# How does one call a method on a 3rd party control without breaking MVVM convention?

Tags: c#, mvvm, telerik, mvvm-light, windows-phone-8

My specific issue is an attempt to execute the Telerik DataBoundListBox method StopPullToRefreshLoading(true) from my ViewModel.  The difficulty is that I do not want to break MVVM convention by putting application logic in the code behind.

I'm relatively new to MVVM and I'm not sure what the proper convention is for interacting with methods on controls on the view.  I've done numerous searches on the topic and I've yet to find a solution that I can apply to my situation.  I suspect I've probably come across the answer but I'm not drawing the proper conclusions.

It seems like this would be a common situation with 3rd party controls but maybe I'm just not thinking about the problem in the proper way.

I'm building my first Windows 8 Phone app using MVVM Light.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of people get very hung up thinking that when following MVVM you MUST NOT HAVE CODE IN THE CODE BEHIND!!! This simply isn't the case, a design pattern like MVVM is there to make the code more maintainable. If something relates directly to the UI only and doesn't care about information in the viewmodel class then by all means put it in the code behind. I had the same situation when I was using third partly controls, sometimes there is no other option that isn't as bad or worse than putting code in the code behind.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I plan to put the control's method call in a function in the code behind and then call the code behind method from my ViewModel.  I should be able to adhere to the requirement that there is no view specific logic in the ViewModel if I don't explicitly couple the function call to my ViewModel.  I have a lot left to learn.

Answer (score 1):

First I agree with Chris McCabe on this, design patterns are a guideline, a framework, a suggestion.  They are not rules to live-or-die by.  That being said, you should be able to join the two (VM/Telerik) without introducing 'real' business logic into the UI.

The first possibility is to use an event on the controller.  The UI can subscribe to this event to forward the call to the Telerik control; however, the UI *should not* decide when it is called.

```
class MyModel {
    public event EventHandler StopRefreshLoading;
}

class myForm : Form {

    public myForm(MyModel data)
    {
        data.StopRefereshLoading += (o, e) => this.CustomControl.StopPullToRefreshLoading(true);
        // ... etc
    }
```

Frankly, I prefer using interfaces for this type of behavior.  It's then easy for the controller to force implementations to update to a new contract requirement.  The downside is that the interfaces can become too verbose in a complex UI making them difficult to write tests for.

```
interface IMyModelView {
    void StopRefreshLoading();
}

class myForm : Form, IMyModelView {

    void IMyModelView.StopRefreshLoading()
    {
        this.CustomControl.StopPullToRefreshLoading(true);
    }
```

Either direction you go some violation of the UI design pattern is likely to occur; however, in the real world there are no points for strictly adhering to a specific pattern.  The patterns are there as an aid to make the code more reliable, testable, flexible, whatever.  Decide why you are using a pattern and you will be able to evaluate when can safely violate that pattern.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've gotten consistent advice about not trying to be too adamant about following MVVM on everything.  Since the method I'm trying to call is related to the control and not to my application logic I've been convinced it is OK to call from code behind.  Thanks again.